# T-SQL Syntax - word parser

Tags: t-sql

I have a word list in a variable. The words are comma delimited. I am trying to save them to individual record in a database. I found another question which does this and works, but it saves every word. I tried to modify it so that I only save unique words, and count duplicate as I go. I think the logic below is correct, but my syntax is not working.

1. if @FoundWord = 0 SET @WordsUsed = @WordsUsed + '*' + @Word + '*'

** is not concatenating the next word onto the end of the @WordsUsed variable

2. if @FoundWord = 0 INSERT INTO mydata.dbo.words (ProjectNumber, WordCount, Word) VALUES( '5', '1', @Word )

** doesn't seem to be doing anything at all ... I'm getting no records written to the words table

The entire code follows:

```
declare @SplitOn nvarchar(5) = ','
BEGIN
DECLARE @split_on_len INT = LEN(@SplitOn)
DECLARE @start_at INT = 1
DECLARE @end_at INT
DECLARE @data_len INT
DECLARE @WordsUsed varchar(max)
DECLARE @FoundWord int
DECLARE @Word varchar(100)

Set @WordsUsed = '**'
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    SET @end_at = CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@txt1,@start_at)
    SET @data_len = CASE @end_at WHEN 0 THEN LEN(@txt1) ELSE @end_at-@start_at END
    set @Word = SUBSTRING(@txt1,@start_at,@data_len)
    SET @FoundWord = CHARINDEX('*' & @Word & '*', @WordsUsed)
    if @FoundWord = 0 SET @WordsUsed = @WordsUsed & '*' & @Word & '*'
    if @FoundWord = 0 INSERT INTO mydata.dbo.words (ProjectNumber, WordCount, Word) VALUES( '5', '1', @Word )
    if @FoundWord > 0 Update mydata.dbo.words set WordCount = WordCount + 1 where projectnumber = 5 and word = @word
    IF @end_at = 0 BREAK
    SET @start_at = @end_at + @split_on_len
END

RETURN
END;
```

Comment: Why not just use the code you found that works to import to a temp table, then do a `INSERT INTO mydata.dbo.words (...) SELECT DISTINCT ... FROM #words`?

Comment: I do need the word count.

Comment: Also, in the light of a little sleep .... I don't have the data in a temp table. I have it in a variable. What I done is to take a longer document, read it into a nvarchar(max) variable in my tsql script, strip all all the non-alph characters, replace spaces with commas. then eliminate extra commas.

So I'm sitting there with @txt as a comma delimited list of words. My final goal is either a table with a word in each row, or with a unique word and a count of it in each row. I can set to the second with an (insert into ... select) query if I have the first.

Comment: PS. The query I have which works takes more than an hour to run for a 100,000 word list, so I'm trying to come up with something more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function you can try. It splits an unlimited-sized string based on the delimiter of your choice. The output of the function is a table - so you can then select distinct from that to store your word list.  You'd call it something like:

```
insert YourWordlistTable ( Word )  --> just making up table/column names here
select distinct Data 
from dbo.StringSplit( @yourVar, ',' )
```

Here's the definition of the function:

```
create function dbo.StringSplit
(
   @string nvarchar( max ),
   @delimiter nvarchar( 255 )
)
returns @t table ( Id int, Data nvarchar( 4000 ) )
as begin

    with Split( startPosition, endPosition )
    as
    (
      select 
         cast( 0 as bigint ) as startPosition, 
         charindex( @delimiter, @string ) as endPosition
      union all
      select 
         endPosition + 1, charindex( @delimiter, @string, endPosition + 1 )
      from 
         Split
      where 
         endPosition > 0
    )
    insert @t
    select 
      row_number() over ( order by ( select 1 ) ) as Id,
      substring( @string, startPosition, coalesce( nullif( endPosition, 0 ), len( @string ) + 1 ) - startPosition ) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS as Data
    from 
      Split 
    option( maxrecursion 0  );

    return;
end
```

I originally posted, then deleted, then reposted this when I realized I'd given an inline function I use that never got called on strings longer than 100 words. I've since modified it to support indefinite recursion - although it can't be an inline function this way.

Inline functions are generally faster because SQL can incorporate the inline function's statement into the query plan of the statements that call the function. However, that does not appear to be an option available in an inline function.

Comment: Yeah. :-) This reduced the time to split my data into unique rows from about an hour to about instantaneous.

Great job and MANY THANKS!!

Comment: Oops. I just noticed that the result set I get is a list of the distinct words.

Do you know how to modify that function so that it returns every word, so that I can then count their occurrences? - Thanks.

Comment: Just `select data` instead of `select distinct data` in the top select - the split function itself doesn't do the distinct.  BTW - the function _is_ case sensitive. If you don't want that, you'll want to remove collation.

Comment: Duh, the distinct when I call the function ... sorry about that.

*** You just beat me to it ... I appreciate your continued help.

Comment: Been there, glad to help :-)

Comment: And I even got the count for free, from Binesh's idea, but modifying the call as follows:

    select data, count(*) as WordUsed
    from mydata.dbo.stringSplit( @txt1, ',' )
    group by data
    order by COUNT(*) desc;

Answer (score 0):

why can't you use 
`select count(distinct value) from dbo.split(',',@txt1)`  where @txt1 is he string will give you distinct count of words

If you are looking for word wise count

```
select value,count(1) from dbo.split(',',@txt1) group by value
```

shoud do this

Comment: It sounds great. Where does the dbo.split come from?

Comment: I'm understanding like you need to insert distinct count of the words into table with comma seperated values.For eg:if text is "abc,def,abc" you need to insert one record with count 2. Am i right?

Comment: If you are looking for word wise count see updated answer

Comment: Close.  abc with count 2, and def with count 1.

Comment: See the updated answer.Performance wise & readablility wise it will be far better. If you are finding out the @txt from table row do a cross apply so that you can avoid while loop also